# Bind Ctrl+J to enter in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to enter (return) in sublime text 2. I am unfamiliar with the command name for enter in sublime text, but I would like something like so in .sublime-keymap:

```
[
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+j"],
        "command": <ENTER>
    }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `Preferences > Key Bindings - User`
2. Add the following:

`{"keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n"}}`